# How to append textview to radiogroup dynamically in android

Tags: android, dynamically-generated, android-checkbox, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

Hi everyone,
               we want add textview beside of radiogroup dynamically.Based on service response we need append label to radiogroup without using xml.
In some situation based on max length radio

[[image: Here we are showing checkboxes,but based on response it will changes to radiogroup with in radiobutton]]

here is below code

```
  final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
            rg.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
            rg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[items_list.size()];
            final CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[items_list.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < items_list.size(); i++) {

                LinearLayout ll_orientaion = new LinearLayout(this);
                ll_orientaion.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2.0f));
                ll_orientaion.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                ll_orientaion.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                ll_orientaion.setWeightSum(2);
                ll_orientaion.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


                if (max == 1) {

                    rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
                    rb[i].setText(pd.getName());
                    rb[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    ll_orientaion.addView(rb[i]);

                    if (pd.getSelected_status().equals("true")) {
                        rb[i].setChecked(true);

                    }

                    hashMap_rdlist.put(rb[i].getText().toString(), rdd);

                    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                            ProductOptions rd_getlist = new ProductOptions();

                            int checkedRadioButtonId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedRadioButtonId);
                            //  Toast.makeText(ProductOptionsActivity.this, radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            String rd_name = (String) radioButton.getText();

                    });
                } else {

                    cb[i] = new CheckBox(this);
                    cb[i].setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
                    cb[i].setText(pd.getName());
                    cb[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    ll_orientaion.addView(cb[i]);


                    }

                    final int finalI = i;

                    cb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                            ProductOptions rd_getlist = new ProductOptions();
                            String check_name = (String) cb[finalI].getText();

                            if (isChecked) {

                                check_count++;


                            } else {
                                check_count--;

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                // Log.d("checklist",""+productoptions_skuId);

                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams tv1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
                tv.setLayoutParams(tv1);
                tv1.weight = 2;
                tv1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                tv.setText(pd.getSalePrice());
                tv.setTextSize(14);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.END);
                if (pd.getSalePrice().equals("0.0")) {
                    tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                ll_orientaion.addView(tv);
                rg.addView(ll_orientaion);
            }
```

The main problem,when we are adding LinearLayout to radiGroup View is getting Perfect but RadioButton action is not working i.e,

`rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {}`

Please Guide us
Advance thanks!

Comment: `RadioGroup` will only work for its immediate children which are either themselves or are subclass of `RadioButton`. It seems you are adding `LinearLayout` as `RadioGroup` children.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom adapter for the listview with CheckedTextView.

Comment: What problem does it create for you?

Comment: problem means checkbutton has multi options
but radiobutton has singleoption checked

Comment: you can make your listview singleitem checked to true. it will use the checked textview to select only one item from the list.

Comment: I am insisting you to use checkedtextview instead of radiobutton.